# Proving a linear operator is onto

Tags: linear-algebra

The original question comes in two parts. The first part is: Let T be a linear operator on V. If $||T(x)|| = ||x||$, then T is **one-to-one**. I have done it as follows:

For all x $\in$ $kernel(T)$, then $T(x) = 0$. It follows that $||x|| = ||T(x)|| = ||0|| = 0$, so $x = 0$. Thus the $kernel(T) = {0}$, proving T is one-to-one.

The second part of the question: Let T be a linear operator on V. If $||T(x)|| = ||x||$, then T is **onto**. I assume the proof would be similar to the one above, except that this time I would need to prove that the cokernel of T contains only the zero vector. So perhaps something like this to begin with:

For all x $\in$ cokernel, ...

**I understand what the cokernel of a matrix is, but what about in the case of a function?** (Such as the kernel of T satisfies $T(x) = 0$.) And can anyone show me how this can be done?

Comment: Is $V$ finite dimensional?

Comment: The original question didn't specify, but I assume it is the case.

Comment: If it is the case, since $T\colon V\to V$, then this is an immediate consequence of the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: @BenWest So knowing that T is one-to-one implies T is onto?

Comment: Yes, when $T$ is a linear map between finite dimensional vector spaces of equal dimension.

Comment: I think I got it now. Thanks!